# using classmexer to find memory usage of a custom Stack in java

Tags: java, memory, stack

I wrote some code to determine the memory taken up by various data structures .I used the [classmexer](http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/) api to get the deep/shallow memory .I tried the calls on a custom Stack of Integers implemented using an inner class Node.(I am running this on `ubuntu lucid` )

For the empty Stack,both shallow and deep memories are 16 bytes
For a Stack of 4 Integers,the deep memory is 176 bytes.This figure got me confused ,because calculated the memory by hand as below

Stack of 4 Integers:

```
object overhead = 16 bytes
reference to Node inst variable = 8
primitive type int variable = 4
padding = 4
total = 32

Each entry in stack has
Node = 40 bytes(inner class)
Integer field = 24 
total = 64
```

so, it should be 32+64N

For N = 4, this will be 288

So, why does  classmexer show the memory usage as 176 ?

One more thing.. how do I determine the `machine word size` on my system .I looked in the lang.System class ,but could not find any api for that

here is my code

```
public class MemoryUsage {
    private static void linkedListMemUsage(){
        StackOfIntegers si1 = new StackOfIntegers();

        long deepmem = MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(si1);
        long shallowmem = MemoryUtil.memoryUsageOf(si1);

        System.out.println("\nfor an empty stack of integers");
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        System.out.println(si1.getClass().getSimpleName()+" took deep:"+deepmem+" bytes");
        System.out.println(si1.getClass().getSimpleName()+" took shallow:"+shallowmem+" bytes");

        StackOfIntegers si2 = new StackOfIntegers();
        si2.push(new Integer(100));
        si2.push(new Integer(200));
        si2.push(new Integer(300));
        si2.push(new Integer(400));

        deepmem = MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(si2);
        shallowmem = MemoryUtil.memoryUsageOf(si2);

        System.out.println("\nfor a stack of 4 integers");
        System.out.println("*************************");
        System.out.println(si1.getClass().getSimpleName()+" took deep:"+deepmem+" bytes");
        System.out.println(si1.getClass().getSimpleName()+" took shallow:"+shallowmem+" bytes");


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        linkedListMemUsage();
    }
    class StackOfIntegers{
        private int N;
        private Node first;

        public void push(Integer item){
        Node old = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = old;
        N++;
        }
        private class Node{
            Integer item;
            Node next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: machine word size: 64-bit for a 64-bit OS and CPU, 32-bit almost otherwise on modern machines.

Comment: is there a java code snippet/api for this

Comment: ok, I tried `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` and this printed 32 .. It seems the JRE is 32 bit.Probably why the calculation is wrong